# Passing :new to Rails url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing, restful-url

Maybe I'm stupid but Rails provides this nifty syntax for generating URL's like so:

```
url_for([user, comment]) # => /users/1/comment/1
```

Passing `:edit` allows me to create something like this:

```
url_for([:edit, user, comment]) # => /users/1/comment/1/edit
```

but is there some way to do following?

```
url_for([:new, user, comments]) # => NoMethodError: undefined method `new_user_comments_url'
```

---

**UPDATE:** Added more information.

My routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
  resources :comments
end

resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

My problem here is, that I can't use Rails auto-generated url helper (`user_comments_url`), because I'm sharing the views for both user comments and post comments.

There are two workarounds (but no one feels like the "Rails"-way) for my problem:

1. Adding logic to the view, e.g. some if conditions.
2. Defining my own url helpers like `new_parent_comment(user_or_blog)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found a solution, but I'm not sure if this is the intended one:

```
url_for([:new, user, :comment]) # => '/users/1/comments/new'

url_for([:new, post, :comment]) # => '/posts/1/comments/new'
```

Answer (score 4):

Stuck with the same problem, and found next solution (tested on Rails 5.2):

```rb
url_for([user, Comment, action: :new])
```

where `Comment` model class name.

By the way, `action` also could be `:edit`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Rails Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_options) url_for uses the class name of the object passed to generate the RESTful route.  It also states that with nested routes it can not make this assumption correctly:

> If you have a nested route, such as admin_workshop_path you’ll have to call that explicitly (it’s impossible for url_for to guess that route).

I would suggest using a named route here something like `new_user_comment_path()`. I am assuming you have set up your routes.rb something like:

```
resources :users do
  resources :comments do 
  end 
end
```

Additionally you can run `rake routes` to print out the proper names for all your routes.
Hope this helps, 
/Salernost

Answer (score 0):

Could this simply be a typo? I think the last line should read `comment`, not `comments`:

```
url_for([:new, user, comment])
```

(Assuming your `comment` variable has been defined.)

Comment: No unfortunately no typo, calling it so returns either ```'/users/1/comments/new/1'``` (if comment is already persisted) or results in the error mentioned in my question already.